# Mikrotik bonding

Tags: mikrotik

Настраиваю балансировку двух каналов на mikrotike и возникла проблема.

Есть два adsl модема подключенных к eth3 и eth4 портам микротика. Eth2 смотрит в локальную суть.

Создал bonding интерфейс в качестве slaves указал eth3 и eth4, режим "balance xor", уровень 3 и 4 модели OSI. Скорость ужасная но трафик идет через оба интерфейса (eth3 и eth4). Отключаю один из интерфейсов eth3 или eth4, инет летает.

Подскажите причину проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Бондинг работает только при условии, что на второй стороне тоже включен бондинг. Чего у вас, как понимаете, нету и не предвидится. Распределение сетевой нагрузки для двух подключений по интернету реализуется совершенно иначе - средствами NAT, например.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, Вы уже и сами догадались, что все очень просто и логично...

1. работают оба канала - все в штатном режиме, пакеты распределяются, все ок
2. отвалился один канал - а микрот-то об этом не знает... поскольку Вы не сказали ему, что надь периодически проверять доступность канала и, в случае отваливания,:

   - прекращать его использование
   - проверять доступность канала и, в случае его (канала) самоподнятия:

     - снова использовать канал

   вот он (микрот) и шлет пакеты с шустрыми мегагерцами на энергичные коннекты в отвалившийся канал. Но, поскольку канал отвален, ни пакеты, ни все остальное никуда не попадает и ничего назад не возвращает.
3. отрублен один интерфейс - "Йоу!" кричит микрот, поскольку следить за своими интерфейсами умеет сам. "Теперь все легко и просто", продолжает он радоваться и гонит весь траф через оставшийся интерфейс.

ЗЫ У Вас всего две DSL-ки? Тогда микрот - это из пушки по воробьям... Хотя и фэншуйненько;)

ЗЗЫ Есть вполне неплохая тётя Вика

Comment: Скорость ужасная не зависимо отвалился или нет канал. Когда оба канала работают и соединение с инетом с установлено то скорость никакая и пакеты теряются.Может быть дело в Link Monitor, у меня стоит none.

Comment: DLS-ки две.